# for loop to iterate the values based on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-3.6, python-3.5

I have a dataset from which i need to take the index 0 and 1 then process the output then take the index value 2 and 3 then process the output and so on.

The code which i have tried takes the value of index 0 and 1 then 1 and 2 then 2 and 3 and so on.

```
for i,r in tqdm(gf.iterrows()):
lp = 0
for v in range(0, 10 + 1):
    lp += r.length_10
    ix.append(i)
    basket.append(r.line.interpolate(lp))
```

The code must take the index value of o and 1 then 2 and 3 then 4 and 5 and so on....0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for v in range(0, 10+1,2):
    print(v,v+1)
#prints
#0 1
#2 3
#4 5
#6 7
#8 9
```

Comment: Why do you need that `10+1`? Just do: `for value in range(0, 10, 2)`

Comment: In the question they are using `10+1` or they can use a variable in place of 10

Comment: @fiveelements this is done to include the integer 10 as value in range. Basically  if you would append v to a list you get values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I couldn't understand very well your code. But, I think that the problem occurs here:

```
for v in range(0, 10 + 1):
```

this means that your iterator will go from 0 to 10 one by one, but try to change this line to:

```
for v in range(0, 10 + 1,2):
```

I think this one will do the job